# Universal Analytics event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have JS code that runs on my clients' websites and occasionally reports certain events to GA so that the clients can track them (they are almost click events). For clients that use universal analytics the code I use is:

```
if (typeof ga != "undefined") ga('send', 'event', category, action,opt_label);
```

and usually it works correctly (I'm using the GA debugger extension for chrome to see which values are sent) however with a couple of clients the GA debugger extension returns an error:

```
Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

What does the error mean and why does it happen only on some sites?

Comment: Are any of your clients using GTM?

Comment: @PhilipWalton yes, they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error message:

> Unknown target: undefined

The word "target" refers to the tracker object. If you're using GTM, it creates its own named tracker object in order to not conflict with any existing trackers on the page. But if there's no default tracker already on the page, then any `ga('send', ...)` or `ga('set', ...)` command will fail because they target the default tracker (which in this case doesn't exist).

This is normally not a problem because most analytics.js users use the default tracker, and most GTM user do 100% of their implementation configuration in GTM, and don't write analytics.js code at all, but if you *do* need to write your own analytics.js code *and* use GTM, you'll need to get the GTM tracker object, since the default tracker syntax won't work.

You can get a list of all created trackers in the following way, then you can send the event using the [synchronous calling syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#sync):

```
ga(function() {
  var allTrackers = ga.getAll();
  var firstTracker = allTrackers[0];

  firstTracker.send('event', category, action, opt_label);
});
```

Obviously if you have more than one tracker, you'll have to figure out which one is the GTM tracker.

For more information on working with named tracker objects and/or using multiple trackers, check out this developer guide:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers